# Are MEF exports cached or discovering every time on request?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mef

If I have one type MyClass, register with

`[Export(typeof(Myclass))]` 
attribute, and

`[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]`

or

`[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]`

and later trying to call

`compositionContainer.GetExportedValue<Myclass>()` multiple times.

Question: with the first call, I will get my registered class via MEF - llokup all registered assemblies, then trying to find one registered contract. Question is about second time and so on - will MEF do global lookup again or it caches somewhere internally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> will MEF do global lookup again or it caches somewhere internally

Yes, MEF perfoms some caching and widely uses lazy initialization, if you question is about MEF performance:

1) metadata (composable parts, export definitions and import definitions) is cached. Example:

```
public override IEnumerable<ExportDefinition> ExportDefinitions
{
    get
    {
        if (this._exports == null)
        {
            ExportDefinition[] exports = this._creationInfo.GetExports().ToArray<ExportDefinition>();
            lock (this._lock)
            {
                if (this._exports == null)
                {
                    this._exports = exports;
                }
            }
        }
        return this._exports;
    }
}
```

2) exported *values* are cached too:

```
public object Value
{
    get
    {
        if (this._exportedValue == Export._EmptyValue)
        {
            object exportedValueCore = this.GetExportedValueCore();
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this._exportedValue, exportedValueCore, Export._EmptyValue);
        }
        return this._exportedValue;
    }
}
```

Of course, when using `CreationPolicy.NonShared`, exported value becomes created again and again, when you requesting it. But even in this case "global lookup" isn't performed, because metadata is cached anyway.

Comment: This is incomplete, in the sense that some lookup is still performed on every call. So doing client-side caching if there are many calls to `GetExportedValue` should be done.

Answer (score 0):

It does a lookup every time, when you use `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]`. You then have to implement the caching yourself.

The default implementation is using a Singleton pattern. This equals the attribute `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]`. **This is the best practice**.

For more information, read http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/01/09/mef-for-beginner-part-creation-policy-part-6.aspx

Comment: "It does a lookup every time" - proof?

Comment: I think, that question isn't about caching concrete exported value.

Comment: Actually I want to know, if I widely use some [Import]MyClassObject in many views, how long it will be lookuped for the first&scond&so on time.

Answer (score 0):

Although the values/metadata might be partially cached, doing some performance testing shows that some lookup is performed every time a call to `GetExportedValue` is made. So if you have many calls where you need to get the value, you should do the caching yourself.

```
namespace MEFCachingTest
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Reflection;

    public static class Program
    {
        public static CompositionContainer Container { get; set; }
        public static ComposablePartCatalog Catalog { get; set; }

        public static ExportedClass NonCachedClass
        {
            get
            {
                return Container.GetExportedValue<ExportedClass>();
            }
        }

        private static ExportedClass cachedClass;
        public static ExportedClass CachedClass
        {
            get
            {
                return cachedClass ?? (cachedClass = Container.GetExportedValue<ExportedClass>());
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            Container = new CompositionContainer(Catalog);

            const int Runs = 1000000;
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            // Non-Cached.
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
            {
                var ncc = NonCachedClass;
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Non-Cached: Time: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

            // Cached.
            stopwatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
            {
                var cc = CachedClass;
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("    Cached: Time: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
    }

    [Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public class ExportedClass
    {
    }
}
```

For more variations, look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/DanielRose/d79f0da2ef61591176ce

On my computer, Windows 7 x64, .NET 4.5.2:

```
Non-Cached: Time: 00:00:02.1217811
    Cached: Time: 00:00:00.0063479
```

Using MEF 2 from NuGet:

```
Non-Cached: Time: 00:00:00.2037812
    Cached: Time: 00:00:00.0023358
```

In the actual application where I work, this made the application 6x slower.