# Why is getting Exports in MEF so slow?

Tags: c#, plugins, mef, composition

I create a MEF container as follows:

```
        //Compose Plugins
        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        IEnumerable<string> directories = FileIO.GetAllSubDirectories(PluginRootDirectory);
        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directory);
            aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(catalog);
        }

        Container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
        Container.ComposeParts(Container);
```

I then try to get exports as follows:

```
    public Dictionary<string, T> GetPlugins<T>()
    {
        var exports = Container.GetExports<T, IPluginAttribute>();
        return exports.ToDictionary(i => i.Metadata.PluginName, i => i.Value);
    }
```

- The first code snippet is executed in the constructor.
- The second code snippet requests plugins of a specific type and is always executed after the first code snipped executed.
- Executing the second code snippet for the first time takes very long time; however, subsequent requests run fast.

Question: How can I ensure the container is composed before requesting exports/plugins? I want even the first request `GetPlugins<T>()` to run fast. I can live with longer initialization times but right now it seems the composition of the container is delayed until actually requesting exported plugins.

Comment: You can create instances in totally different assemblies and namespaces using `Activator.CreateInstance()`.  You can also try `CreateInstance()` in FasterFlect.  http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/discussions/361075

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I am aware of that but as pointed out I appreciate in MEF the advantage of getting all instances that implement one matching interface, for example. With Activator I need to specify and know each individual plugin name in a plugin directory.

Comment: Perhaps that's why it's slow.  It takes time to reflect all that metadata.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, apparently, that is why I wonder about other solutions. To my knowledge, MEF creates a `DirectoryCatalog` by scanning each and every .dll even if the dlls are just dependencies of the actual plugins. Correct me if I am wrong but I feel that is horribly inefficient. If creating the same number of instances via basic reflection takes 1/15th of the time MEF takes then I wonder whether the benefit of being able to import plugins that implement a specific interface without having to know the plugin class names outweighs the slowdown.

Comment: "System.Compostion.*_ is a lightweight version of MEF, which has been optimized for static composition scenarios and provides faster compositions." -- https://mef.codeplex.com/

Comment: Anyway, the last time I did something like this, I wired up `Activator.CreateInstance()` using an XML configuration file.   It was so simple and straightforward that I never bothered with MEF.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes I would go that route as well but I have over 30 plugins of which many derive from different interfaces. One question: Do you happen to know in MEF when the composition container gets constructed? The first code snipped above is in my Mef helper class constructor but the container does not seem to be created even when the constructor is invoked. The first time I call `GetPlugins<T>()` it takes incredibly long, but when I call the method a second time, even specifying a different type `T` it is very fast. It seems something gets delayed in the composition container creation

Comment: Sounds like it's caching the reflected metadata.  It would be nice if you could just serialize that data out to a file for caching purposes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274475

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks, I will work a bit more with MEF, if I can get the composition container created in a different task at application startup then I would potentially be fine as all subsequent requests for meta data as well as values (= actual plugin instances) are executed fast after this initial first request.

Comment: _"If not, I am at this point open to dump MEF **and look for a different plugin technology. Any ideas?** "_ - possibly: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract **opinionated answers** and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_  Other than that, how many files are in your child folders?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks a lot for your explanations and links. I got the point about caching meta data and appreciate your help. If you like to summarize your points in an a quick answer then I am happy to mark it as desired answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEF takes time if there are many files to parse via directory catalog.It will try to parse ALL the binares in the directory whether managed or unmanaged.

Also it will cache class not marked as Export too as MEF allows you to import classes by name even if they dont have a Export attribute.

Try having only single dummy dll with your blank classes to see if the issue is with too many files or MEF.

Comment: the issue is that the first request to export (please see my 2nd code snippet) takes very long while all subsequent requests are fast. I thought my first code snippet in my Mef Utility class takes care of the Container composition but apparently this is delayed until an actual request is made. I wonder whether I can force container composition?

Comment: @MattWolf Just ask for a dummy classes instance in your utility. See if that helps.

Comment: It certainly helps but I like to rather enforce container composition at the time of creation. But thanks for the pointer.